# Initializing std::map in a call to a class constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, initializer-list, stdmap

I've seen the exact syntax I'm trying with a [void function](https://ideone.com/vFRs7Z), but I can't figure out why it is not working in my code:

Constructor:

```
 class Input
 {
 public:
    Input(const std::map<std::string, void(*)(void)> &arg_0)
      { //...code...// }
 };
```

Call to constructor with a temporary std::map:

```
  Input  _Input(
    std::map<std::string, void(*)(void)> {
      {"exit", [](){exit(1);}}
    }
  );
```

Also, just the slightest change to

```
std::map<std::string, void(*)(void)> NAME = {
  {"exit", [](){exit(1);}
}
```

is enough to resolve the problem, and for some reason, NAME also goes out of scope (Which is what I want). So basically, I know the solution, but I want to know why the first code isn't working.
P.S. The error is 
`error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
IN
std::map<std::string, void(*)(void)> {`

## EDIT:

I see, the exact way I call the constructor is apparently important:

```
class BackEnd
{
private:
  Input  _Input(
    std::map<std::string, void(*)(void)> {
      {"exit", [](){exit(1);}}
    }
  );
};
```

In this case, It stops working and throws an error.
Example: https://ideone.com/ikGUGF

Comment: http://cpp.sh/4utj4 ?

Comment: @tkausl I see, hmm, I'm going to double check my code.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @BiagioFesta `sudo g++-4.8 *.cpp -o "main" -pthread -std=c++1y -Wall -pedantic-errors;` But that isn't the problem, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The solution was to use the new Uniform Initialization syntax instead of the old Object Initialization. No Idea *why*, maybe someone could clarify.
2. That's a lot of down-votes for a legitimate question that ***nobody*** was able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution was to use the new Uniform Initialization syntax instead of the old Object Initialization. No Idea why, maybe someone could clarify.

It sounds to me like *[most vexing parse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)*.

Indeed in your code:

```
Input  _Input(
  std::map<std::string, void(*)(void)> {
  // -----------------------------------^
      {"exit", [](){exit(1);}}
    }
 );
```

`Input _Input(...)` could be interpreted as a function definition, and so, since the standard, the compiler does.

That thesis is reinforced by the error:

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
```

That' because the compiler expects a `)` in order to close the signature of the function.

As you've already find out, one solution consists in the usage of the *uniform initialization syntax*.
That because the code is no more ambiguous.

---

> That's a lot of down-votes for a legitimate question that nobody was able to answer.

I agree with you just for the fact a down-votes should imply a comment in order to improve a question itself.

Anyway I hope you can find useful this answer.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be it. Thank you :)